# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When a new order arises, I want to update the number of products again and an error occurred.
The program reported an error in the command:productDao.updateProduct(product);

```
@RequestMapping("checkOut")
    public String checkOut(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        Orders orders = new Orders();
        List<OrderDetail> orderDetailList = (List<OrderDetail>) session.getAttribute("orderDetailList");
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (OrderDetail orderDetail : orderDetailList) {
            totalPrice = totalPrice + orderDetail.getUnitPrice() * orderDetail.getQuantity();
        }
        int shipPrice = 40000;
        int totalPriceOrder = totalPrice + shipPrice;
        if (orderDetailList.size() != 0) {
            orders.setShipAddress(user.getAddress());
            orders.setUser(user);
            orders.setStatus(1);
            orders.setTotalPrice(totalPriceOrder);
            LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
            orders.setOrderDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(currentDate));
        }
        boolean bl = ordersDao.insertOrders(orders);
        if (bl) {
            int temp = 0;
            for (OrderDetail orderDetail : orderDetailList) {
                orderDetail.setOrders(orders);
                orderDetailDao.insertOrderDetail(orderDetail);

                Product product = orderDetail.getProduct();
                int quantityToReduce = orderDetail.getQuantity();
                int currentQuantity = product.getQuantity();
                if (currentQuantity >= quantityToReduce) {
                    product.setQuantity(currentQuantity - quantityToReduce);
                    productDao.updateProduct(product);
                }

                temp++;
            }

            if (temp == orderDetailList.size()) {
                orderDetailList.clear();
                session.setAttribute("orderDetailList", orderDetailList);
            }
        }
        if (orderDetailList.size() == 0) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendMail(user.getEmail(), mailAutoDao.getMailById(2).getMailType(), mailAutoDao.getMailById(2).getMailContent());
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            return "redirect:/home";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/listCart";
        }
    }
```

My program gives an error when trying to update a product
My DAO function:

```
@Override
    public boolean updateProduct(Product product) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.update(product);
            tx.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I go to the admin page to update the product, everything goes normally, the error only appears when the user makes a purchase

I tried many ways to fix it but couldn't, hope you can help, thanks